# Monitor/observe hotspot connection status

Tags: android, monitor, wifimanager, hotspot, android-connectivitymanager

My app needs to connect to another device via hotspot. It will only form a closed network (no internet access) Internet will be accessed via mobile data. How can I monitor the status of the hotspot connection programmatically? I want certain activities to be executed only when this connection is established.  The app should just wait for the connection from the other device.

I am working on android 13

I have looked into few APIs for android WifiManager but not able to identify a suitable one.